# Call synchronous webservice methods asynchronously

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, task

I have to call a webservice method about a hundred times in a loop with different parameters everytime.
The webservice has only sync methods. Currently I am testing this in an console application and it takes over ten minutes to get the data when doing it synchronously!

What i want:
Run 10 requests in parallel. When they have finished, execute the next ten calls.
This should of course be async.

The functionality will be hosted in an IIS hosted wcf service.

Overview:
Client calls wcf service with params once. The wcf service method should call another webservice a hundred times asynchronously and save the final data to Excel.

I read, that **Task.Run** isn't a good idea when used in web application.

So, how to call sync web service methods asynchronously in a web context?

I am using the [CRM Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44567), Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

```
  var orders = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple( new FetchExpression(strXmlFetch));
```

RetrieveMultiple gets an xml fragment (strXmlFetch) where the query is defined and executes the request.
The method resides here:

> **Namespace** Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client 
>   **Class** OrganizationServiceProxy

```
public EntityCollection RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query);
```

Under the hood the client SDk does the follwoing when calling RetrieveMultiple.

```
using (OrganizationServiceContextInitializer organizationServiceContextInitializer = new OrganizationServiceContextInitializer(this))
{
    entityCollection = base.ServiceChannel.Channel.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    return entityCollection;
}
```

I didn't implement anything yet, as i need a starting point for the async execution for the requests.

Comment: You can use Parallel.ForEach (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Evk Parallel API for Network IO, never a good idea, will be wasting resources, it shall be Async-Await, calling a Synchronous method internally or may be Async if available

Comment: But OP says his webservice only has synchronous methods. Of course it's better to leverage async IO, but question states that's not possible. If you will call this synchronous method using async\await and Task.Run - will change nothing.

Comment: Why can't that be called, just that it would need an Async wrapper over Sync, which is Anti Pattern, but that's the only way to call Synchronous methods Asynchronously, using Async-Await

Comment: OP is mostly pointing to no Async method returning the Task available by default, since a standard Web service will have Async methods pertaining to APM

Comment: As I understand, author has some third-party code which calls that webservice, and this code does not use async IO. So this third-party code, for example, does not use HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync, but uses HttpWebRequest.GetResponse, and author cannot change this code.

Comment: Can you show us some code of the client? I'm confused about how a web service can be synchronous at all. The client is hitting a URL and waiting for a response - from the client's perspective that can absolutely be async

Comment: @n8wrl this often happens when you use third party code which you cannot modify.

Comment: @Legends: Please post some code. What kind of APIs do you have available?

Comment: @StephenCleary I am using the CRM 2015 SDK, provided a link above.
From my console application I managed it using `Task.Run`, but I guess this won't work correctly in a web/wcf application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This should of course be async.

Well, that would be ideal. However, [`OrganizationServiceProxy` does not have asynchronous methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) ([neither does `IOrganizationService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.aspx), so using the `ServiceChannel.Channel` directly won't help, either).

So, the first thing to do is ask Microsoft to add asynchronous APIs to that client library.

> I read, that Task.Run isn't a good idea when used in web application.

Normally that's true; you'd want to call asynchronous APIs. Which in this case aren't available.

> So, how to call sync web service methods asynchronously in a web context?

This isn't possible. Your options are:

1. Just keep it synchronous, one at a time. Yeah, it'll take longer than it should.
2. Make it *parallel*.

The problem with parallel processing on the server side is that you're now using `N` threads for a single request, which can *really quickly* bring your web server to its knees. I do not recommend this approach in production code, especially if it's exposed over the Internet.

However, if you're **sure** that there won't be too many calls to your WCF service, you *can* implement it in parallel.

Since you need to collect results from the parallel query, I'd recommend using [Parallel LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx) (`AsParallel`) specifying `WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)`, something like:

```
IEnumerable<EntityCollection> GetAll(OrganizationServiceProxy proxy, IEnumerable<QueryBase> queries)
{
  return queries.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
      .Select(query => proxy.RetrieveMultiple(query));
}
```

Comment: Currently I do it with Task.Run, but with ParallelForEach would be a way smarter and easier. So, for example, I need to fetch 50000 records, when doing it sync, 50 calls each returning 1000 and each request takes 5 seconds, in total 250 seconds. With parallelism (WithDegree(50)) I would expect it to be accomplished in about 5 to 8 seconds approx. But In my case it takes 90% of the time when running in sync mode. I guess there is something on the serverside blocking...?

Comment: In my code I use `WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)`, with 20 I start to receive timeouts.

Comment: @Legends: It's quite possible that the server side is limiting you to one request at a time. Or you're hitting some other bottleneck. Timeouts can occur in this scenario, because the timeout is from when you make the request to when the result arrives - if the server is throttling you, then some of your requests will have artificially long times.

Answer (score 1):

> The webservice has only sync methods

Web services by default produce `Asynchronous` methods pertaining to `BeginXX, EndXX`, which are part of `Asynchronous Programming Model`, but they are not the one which can be consumed by `Async-Await`, since they don't return the `Task`.

> What i want: Run 10 requests in parallel. When they have finished, execute the next ten calls. This should of course be async.

In truly `Async` calls as no `threads` are invoked and as it works on IO completion ports, therefore you can start many more calls, than just 10. Otherwise the logic to schedule 10 Async requests at a time has to be custom, there's no out of box mechanism to do it, even while using `Threadpool`, there's no guarantee of number of requests in parallel, though you may set the `Max Degree of Parallelism`, for higher limit for Parallel APIs.

> Overview: Client calls wcf service with params once. The wcf service method should call another webservice a hundred times asynchronously and save the final data to Excel.

You would prefer all the calls to be Async, so that the Ui thread is not blocked, whether its to the wcf service or web service.

> I read that `Task.Run` isn't a good idea when used in web application.

True, since a `ThreadPool` thread is getting invoked, which will do nothing post dispatching the `IO` call to `Web Service`

> So, how to call sync web service methods asynchronously in a web context?

Needs an Async wrapper over Sync method, which is Anti-Pattern, but there's no other option. This would need a `ThreadPool` thread, something like:

```
public class AsyncWrapper
{   
  public async Task CallWcfAsync(<Parameters>)
  {  
       SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = 
       SynchronizationContext.Current;

    try
    {
      SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
      await Task.Run(() => CallWcfMethod(<Parameters>));
    }
    finally
    {             
      SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext
      (_synchronizationContext);
    }   
  }
}
```

Important Points:

1. `CallWcfAsync` is the `Async wrapper method` which you need.
2. Notice I have set the Synchronization context to `Null` before execution and then reset it, this is similar in behavior to `ConfigureAwait(false)`, else in the web applications it would lead to deadlock, as `Sychronization Context` waited upon is blocked.

Comment: So this last wrapper is the same as using Parallel.ForEach, just less convenient, because you need to implement batching (max 10 parallel requests) youself.

Comment: @Evk On thinking little further, this would have far more benefits than using plain `Parallel.For`, beside having the control of `SynchronizationContext`, to avoid deadlock, it will not be blocking call like Parallel, so will free up calling / Ui thread to process other tasks,  which is the essence of the IO calls.

Comment: Why down-vote, at-least show the bare minimal courtesy to provide the explicit reason

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, and real downvoter won't receive notification with your question.

Comment: @Evk, thanks, actually I am Ok with down vote, provided there's rationale, else its misuse and I have no mechanism to know.

Comment: Agree, the way to use synchronous web services asynchronously is Task.Run(), however it blocks a thread but it is required if parallel execution is needed.

Comment: @Sarvesh Mishra it does use a `Thread Pool thread`, but not a blocking call like `Parallel.For`,being `Async-Await, which will free up the caller

Comment: @MrinalKamboj the caller will be free, but the thread calling `CallWcfMethod(<Parameters>)` will be waiting for the time being.

Comment: Agreed but in `Parallel.For` both will be blocked